# Angular Material 14: Loading animation on Button not running

Tags: angular-material

I have an Angular Material Button and when the user clicks data should be loaded and the animation should be shown. Therefore I have created

```
@keyframes spinner {
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.spinner:before {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    animation: spinner 0.8s linear infinite;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-top-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    content: '';
}
```

Assigning a button the class `spinner` won't initate the animation. I created a [sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6ws4pe). The animation should be visible on button `Sample2`. Any hints?

Comment: I just removed the ```:before``` from selector, animation started working. Though that isn't intended animation. you may need to change it as per your need.

Comment: Thx for testing since this opened the route for the solution. See in the answer. Thx again!!!

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Amit Kumar I figured out that the Material Button has to look like:

```
<button mat-stroked-button [disabled]="true" > 
  <span class="spinner">Sample2</span>
</button>
```

i.e. I need to set the class on the `text` instead of the `mat-button`!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code of [ngx-loading-buttons](https://github.com/dkreider/ngx-loading-buttons/blob/main/projects/ngx-loading-buttons/src/styles.css) it seems there were some changes in animations.
I replaced `:before` with `::after`, and it works without moving styling to `<span ...`.

Now it looks like this

```
@keyframes spinner {
    to {
        transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
}

.spinner::after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    animation: spinner 0.8s linear infinite;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin-top: -10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    border: 2px solid white;
    border-top-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    content: '';
}
```